# Changing JAX-WS default XML namespace prefix

Tags: java, jax-ws

I've generated source codes for an old Web Service using JAX-WS 2.1.7. When I call this service the generated soap message is something like this:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
  <env:Header>
  </env:Header>
  <env:Body>
      ...
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

But the old web service only accepts this format:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    ...
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

As you see the prefix is "soap" instead "env" and there is no header so i got an error complaining about "soap:Body" is required. I can't change the old web service and need to send compatible soap messages. how can i change the prefix to "soap" and also remove "Header"?

Answer (score 5):

You need to create a class that implements `SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>` and that includes something like this:

```
  public boolean handleMessage(final SOAPMessageContext context)
  {
    final Boolean isSoapResponse = (Boolean) context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
    if (!isSoapResponse)
    {
      try
      {
        final SOAPMessage soapMsg = context.getMessage();
        soapMsg.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns:soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
        soapMsg.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().removeAttributeNS("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", "env");
        soapMsg.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().removeAttribute("xmlns:env");
        soapMsg.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().setPrefix("soap");
        soapMsg.getSOAPBody().setPrefix("soap");
        soapMsg.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().getHeader().detachNode();
      }
      catch (SOAPException e)
      {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Then create a handler.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<handler-chains xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
  <handler-chain>
    <handler>
      <handler-name>test.MySoapHandler</handler-name>
      <handler-class>test.MySoapHandler</handler-class>
    </handler>
  </handler-chain>
</handler-chains>
```

And add an annotation to your web service:

`@HandlerChain(file = "handler.xml")`

Comment: it works for me, with a small change, I needed to remove `soapMsg.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().getHeader().detachNode();`

Comment: dear I have the same problem here where  i need to change the prefix of the out request , I am wrapping a soap request with a rest one and inside the rest api I invoking the soap but the I need to change the prefixes before sending the request I am not pretty sure how to apply the suggested solution in my case ..any help .. thanks in advance