# Changing SOAPRequest Prefix in JAX-WS

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, soap-client

How to change SOAP Request prefix in JAX-WS. I updated setprofix method in handlemessage

```
        SOAPMessage msgs = ctx.getMessage();

        SOAPMessage sm = MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_2_PROTOCOL).createMessage();
         sm.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().setPrefix("soap");
         sm.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().removeNamespaceDeclaration("env");
         sm.getSOAPHeader().setPrefix("soap");
         sm.getSOAPBody().setPrefix("soap");*/
```

But Still I am getting the Same Request

```
       <?xml version="1.0"?>
       <S:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```

I needed

```
      <Soap:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```

Please help

Comment: Have you tried to find the namespace??? try to find a method which is somewhat like setNamespace()...it may help..also why is Soap needed instead of s, its just a namespace...

Comment: Your code snippet it's correct. Just tested using Metro JAX-WS distribution 2.2.1-1. It may be a problem with your underlining JAX-WS implementation. Which web service library do you use?

Comment: i have generated the code using WSDL provided using wsimport JDK 1.6. build 27.

Comment: It is using 2.1.6 Version

Comment: is this for an inbound or outbound message?

Comment: outbound message to thrid party

Comment: change "SOAPMessage sm =" to "msgs =" and add to end msgs.saveChanges();

Answer (score 3):

```
    final SOAPMessage soapMsg = context.getMessage();
    soapMsg.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns:soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
    soapMsg.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().removeAttributeNS("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", "env");
    soapMsg.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().removeAttribute("xmlns:env");
    soapMsg.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().setPrefix("soap");
    soapMsg.getSOAPBody().setPrefix("soap");
    soapMsg.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().getHeader().detachNode();
```

Answer (score 3):

I need to change the default prefix from S to soapenv.  Here is what I did:

1. Create an implementation of SOAPHandler, which sets the prefix.

   ```
   public class SoapNamespaceHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>{
       private final static String SOAP_PREFIX = "soapenv";

       @Override
       public boolean handleMessage(final SOAPMessageContext context){
   //only update the namespace prefix for outbound messages (requests)
           final Boolean isSoapRequest = (Boolean)context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
           if (isSoapRequest){
               try{
                   //get the soap message and envelope
                   SOAPMessage soapMsg = context.getMessage();
                   SOAPEnvelope env = soapMsg.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
                   //set the prefix
                   env.setPrefix(SOAP_PREFIX);        
                   // **** apply the changes to the message
                   soapMsg.saveChanges();
               } 
               catch (SOAPException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
       return true;
   }
   ```
2. Do one of the following:

   - create an XML file that functions as a HandlerResolver (see [Changing JAX-WS default XML namespace prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678723/changing-jax-ws-default-xml-namespace-prefix)) and then annotate your web service client class with @HandlerChain(file = "handler.xml")

     ```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <handler-chains xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
         <handler-chain>
             <handler>
                 <handler-name>mypackage.SoapNamespaceHandler</handler-name>
                 <handler-class>mypackage.SoapNamespaceHandler</handler-class>
             </handler>
         </handler-chain>
     </handler-chains>
     ```
   - create an implementation of HandlerResolver ...

     ```
      public class SoapNamespaceHandlerResolver implements HandlerResolver {
         @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes" })
         @Override
         public List<Handler> getHandlerChain(PortInfo portInfo) {
             List<Handler> handlerChain = new ArrayList<Handler>();
             Handler handler = (SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>) new SoapNamespaceHandler();
             String bindingID = portInfo.getBindingID();
             if (bindingID.equals("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/http")) {
                 handlerChain.add(handler);
             } else if (bindingID.equals("http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws/2003/05/soap/bindings/HTTP/")) {
                 handlerChain.add(handler);
             }
             return handlerChain;
         }
     }
     ```

     ... and then programmatically attach your HandlerResolver implementation to your web service client by calling

     ```
        webServiceClient.setHandlerResolver(new SoapNamespaceHandlerResolver());
     ```