# How to enable WS-Addresing in client SOAP request for Grails

Tags: java, xml, web-services, grails, soap

I have a problem with WS-Addresing in SOAP header. I succesfully imported classes from xsd file with configuration, but server require WS-Addressing attributes in soap header("wsa:action", "wsa:to"). Unfortunettly client service dont inject these attributes and server return http code 400 "Bad Request".

How can I automatically inject a proper SOAP header for requests?

I tried with @Addressing(enabled=true, required=true) annotation, but header was wrong for webservice

Configuration in Config.groovy

Service endpoint: https://wyszukiwarkaregontest.stat.gov.pl/wsBIR/UslugaBIRzewnPubl.svc

Main xsd file: https://wyszukiwarkaregontest.stat.gov.pl/wsBIR/wsdl/UslugaBIRzewnPubl.xsd

I use Grails 2.5.0 and plugin grails-cfx

Grails-cfx configuration in Config.groovy

```
birCompanyDataEndPoint {
            wsdl = "wsdl/UslugaBIRzewnPubl.xsd"
            namespace = "pl.truesoftware.crm.company.regon"

            client = true

            contentType = "application/soap+xml"
            mtomEnabled = true
            exsh = true

            or = true

            wsdlArgs = ['-autoNameResolution']

          //  outInterceptors = 'smartApiMetaOutInterceptor'

            clientInterface = IUslugaBIRzewnPubl
            serviceEndpointAddress = "https://wyszukiwarkaregontest.stat.gov.pl/wsBIR/UslugaBIRzewnPubl.svc"
        }
```

## Example

### Plain SOAP request from client service

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <ns2:DaneKomunikat xmlns="http://CIS/BIR/PUBL/2014/07/DataContract" xmlns:ns2="http://CIS/BIR/PUBL/2014/07" xmlns:ns3="http://CIS/BIR/2014/07" xmlns:ns4="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

### With using annotation @Addressing(enabled=true, required=true)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <Action xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://CIS/BIR/PUBL/2014/07/IUslugaBIRzewnPubl/DaneKomunikat</Action>
    <MessageID xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">urn:uuid:f43e7c86-99dd-42fc-a626-ccbd44136682</MessageID>
    <To xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">https://wyszukiwarkaregontest.stat.gov.pl/wsBIR/UslugaBIRzewnPubl.svc</To>
    <ReplyTo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
      <Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</Address>
    </ReplyTo>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <ns2:DaneKomunikat xmlns="http://CIS/BIR/PUBL/2014/07/DataContract" xmlns:ns2="http://CIS/BIR/PUBL/2014/07" xmlns:ns3="http://CIS/BIR/2014/07" xmlns:ns4="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

### Expected

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns="http://CIS/BIR/PUBL/2014/07">
<soap:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
<wsa:To>https://wyszukiwarkaregontest.stat.gov.pl/wsBIR/UslugaBIRzewnPubl.svc</wsa:To>
<wsa:Action>http://CIS/BIR/PUBL/2014/07/IUslugaBIRzewnPubl/DaneKomunikat</wsa:Action>            
</soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <ns:DaneKomunikat/>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

## Update with solution

Created two cfx interceptor. First convert soap addressing tags(Action, To) to acceptable format

```
public class BirSoapHeaderInterceptor extends AbstractSoapInterceptor
{
    static String birSID = ""

    public BirSoapHeaderInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.PRE_PROTOCOL);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) throws Fault
    {
        try
        {
            message.put("disable.outputstream.optimization", true)

            List<Header> soapHeaders = message.getHeaders()

            //----------------- copy values from old header
            String wsaAction = ""
            String wsaTo = ""

            soapHeaders.each { tag ->
                log.debug("Soap request header tag: ${tag.name} ${tag.dataBinding}")

                String tagName = (tag.name as String)
                def objectValue = tag.object?.value

                if (!wsaAction && tagName.contains("Action"))
                    wsaAction = objectValue?.value

                if (!wsaTo && tagName.contains("To"))
                    wsaTo = objectValue?.value
            }

            soapHeaders.clear()

            //-----------------wsa:To
            Header headTo = new Header(new QName("http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing", "To", "wsa"), wsaTo, new JAXBDataBinding(String.class))
            soapHeaders.add(headTo)

            //-----------------wsa:Action
            Header headAction = new Header(new QName("http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing", "Action", "wsa"), wsaAction, new JAXBDataBinding(String.class))
            soapHeaders.add(headAction)

            message.put(Header.HEADER_LIST, soapHeaders)

            //Session identyficator in HTTP Header
            if(birSID.length())
            {
                Map<String, List<String>> outHeaders = (Map<String, List<String>>) message.get(Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS)
                outHeaders.put("sid", Arrays.asList(birSID));
                message.put(Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS, outHeaders);
            }

        } catch (SOAPException e)
        {
            log.error(e)
        }
    }
}
```

Second interceptor converts attributes 'xmlns:soap', 'xmlns:wsa', 'xmlns:soap' with acceptable namespaces

```
class BirSoapContextInterceptor implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>
{
    /*
    Based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678723/changing-jax-ws-default-xml-namespace-prefix
     */
    public boolean handleMessage(final SOAPMessageContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            SOAPMessage soapMsg = context.getMessage();

            SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapMsg.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope()

            soapMsg.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().removeAttributeNS("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", "soap");
            soapMsg.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().removeAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "soap");
            soapMsg.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().removeAttribute("xmlns:soap");
            soapMsg.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().removeNamespaceDeclaration("xmlns:soap")

            envelope.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns:soap", "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope");
            envelope.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns:ns", "http://CIS/BIR/PUBL/2014/07");

            soapMsg.getSOAPHeader().setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns:wsa", "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing")
            soapMsg.getSOAPHeader().setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns:soap", "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope");

            soapMsg.saveChanges()

            context.setMessage(soapMsg)
        } catch (SOAPException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        return false
    }

    @Override
    void close(MessageContext context) {
        log.debug("Closing...")
    }

    @Override
    Set<QName> getHeaders() {
        return null
    }
}
```